# Create NSSet using a predicate from an NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

I am trying to create a NSSet from an NSArray of NSDictionaries. However every time the thread hits my NSSet code it throws a BAD ACCESS error and my app falls over.

```
NSSet *matchingItems = [insProject.ins filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dpc == %@", dpc]];
```

dpc == 2

when I log insProject.ins this is what I get.

```
2013-11-16 16:53:27.148 myAPP[7979:907] Relationship 'ins' on managed object (0x1d570b00) <insProject: 0x1d570b00> (entity: insProject; id: 0x1d575830 <x-coredata://XXXXXXXXXXX/insProject/p2> ; data: <fault>) with objects {(
    <ins: 0x1d59cf60> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59c040 <x-coredata://XXXXXXXXXXX/ins/p50> ; data: {
    dpc = 11;
}),
    <ins: 0x1d59cbe0> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59bf80 <x-coredata://28BFA6C4-F20F-445D-AD93-2CA028303C28/ins/p38> ; data: {
    dpc = 4;
}),
    <ins: 0x1d59cc80> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59bfa0 <x-coredata://28BFA6C4-F20F-445D-AD93-2CA028303C28/ins/p40> ; data: {
    dpc = 7;
}),
    <ins: 0x1d59c900> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59bf50 <x-coredata://28BFA6C4-F20F-445D-AD93-2CA028303C28/ins/p35> ; data: {
    dpc = 9;

}),
    <ins: 0x1d59cd80> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59bfd0 <x-coredata://28BFA6C4-F20F-445D-AD93-2CA028303C28/ins/p43> ; data: {
    dpc = 16;
}),
    <ins: 0x1d59cf20> (entity: ins; id: 0x1d59c030 <x-coredata://28BFA6C4-F20F-445D-AD93-2CA028303C28/ins/p49> ; data: {
    dpc = 2;
})
)}
```

As you can see, there is an item in the array that has dpc == 2 but this NSSet line of code just goes crazy when it tries to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a type mismatch between the format string of your `NSPredicate` and the value of `dpc` that you pass to it: the format string with `%@` expects an object, so passing a primitive type to it triggers undefined behavior.

If `dpc` is an `int`, change the format string to `@"dpc == %d"`; it should fix the problem. Alternatively, make `dpc` an `NSNumber`, and keep the `%@` format:

```
NSNumber *dpc = @2; // This is the new syntax for [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]
```

Comment: wow... i missed that one well and truly.. holy moly.. thank you very much you have no idea how badly i got stuck on this problem... well this is part of a bigger problem I have been stuck on almost all week... thank you very much.